# Maven - should I include dependency that my imported library contains

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Assuming that I have an artifact `my-project-core` that includes some dependencies with library:

```
<artifactId>my-project-core</artifactId>
<name>CORE</name>

...

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bun.puffy</groupId>
    <artifactId>just-the-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I want to use it in new project that have dependency with `my-project-core`

```
<artifactId>new-project-using-core</artifactId>
<name>NEW PROJECT USING CORE</name>

...

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bun.puffy</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- should I also add this ?
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bun.puffy</groupId>
    <artifactId>just-the-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
-->
```

should I add dependency for `just-the-lib` in the new project or should I not do this and depend on the dependency of `my-project-core`? What are pros and cons?

Comment: No, the dependency my-project-core will bring all it needs automatically.

Comment: One exception is: Do you use some classes of the just-the-lib than add otherwise keep it as it.

Comment: As khmarbaise says, if you use apis from just-the-lib, it should be added. Please also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200029/should-you-include-those-dependencies-in-your-pom-that-are-already-the-dependenc/53203321#53203321

Comment: @gjoranv thank you :)

Comment: I think `mvn dependency:analyze` will tell you if your app is directly using classes from a lib that is being included as a transitive dependency (the case @khmarbaise and @gjoranv mention) instead of being directly referenced in the app's POM.